# OpenGL- drawarrays or drawelements?

Tags: opengl

I'm making a small 2D game demo and from what I've read, it's better to use `drawElements()` to draw an indexed triangle list than using `drawArrays()` to draw an unindexed triangle list.

But it doesn't seem possible as far as I know to draw multiple elements that are not connected in a single draw call with `drawElements()`.

So for my 2D game demo where I'm only ever going to draw squares made of two triangles, what would be the best approach so I don't end having one draw call per object?

Comment: `DrawArrays` is a `DrawElements` with linear (0, 1, 2, 3, ...) indices. This is the only difference, so there is nothing you can do with `DrawArrays` that you can't with `DrawElements`

Comment: So how I do draw multiple elements that are not connected in a single draw call with drawElements()?

Comment: What's the problem? Generate linear indices and try it the same way as `DrawArrays`. It will work. Then try to reduce amount of vertices via merging same vertices and re-generating indices. It is unlikely you'll have a lot of same vertices in 2D tho - so you wouldn't have too much benefit from it.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.
I'll try it and come back with the results.

Comment: @keltar: The claim "DrawArrays is DrawElements with linear indices, that is the only difference" is not quite right, it's more like "DrawElements without indices". That is the reason why there exists a performance difference.

Comment: *"But it doesn't seem possible as far as I know to draw multiple elements that are not connected in a single draw call with drawElements()."* - And you drew this conclusion from where (hint: it's wrong).

Comment: @Damon you mean, manually creating linear indices array and feeding it to `DrawElements` could be faster than `DrawArrays`? Unless it's a bug (or, more likely, not optimised route) in graphics driver, i doubt it. Of course if indices _are_ optimised (removed duplicates, reordered to better hit vertex cache) - difference will be more than significant. But keeping in mind that i had experience with buggy drivers - i don't use `DrawArrays` ever, anyway.

Comment: @keltar: That's not a bug, but an implementation detail. The vertex cache is tagged by vertex ID in all current implementations. `DrawArrays` does not set the vertex ID, so the information necessary to reuse an entry from the cache is not there. Another reason is given in jozxyqk's answer: indices are (usually) much smaller than vertices. It's more bandwidth and cache friendly to have another 16-bit index for the same vertex (adjacent tris) than to have the vertex data twice, which you'd need to do with `DrawArrays` (unless everything can be drawn in tri-strips).

Comment: @Damon it's not what've i said. If you have only unique indices - `DrawElements` should be no faster then `DrawArrays` (unless driver have really poor `DrawArrays` implementation). It is duplicates (**if** you have them) that making it faster (less data and possible vertex cache hits). If there is no duplicates - you have only overhead at least to store indices somewhere.

Comment: @keltar: Ah yes, that's of course right. Assuming every vertex is individual (such as in a cloud of triangular particles?) then they're probably identical, or `DrawArrays` may even be faster. Also, of course, in absence of base vertex on very old hardware, `DrawArrays` allows you to draw different objects from one buffer whereas `DrawElements` requires you to bind different buffers or rewrite indices on the CPU. But those are all rather "unusual" cases :-)

Comment: @Damon in a context of question (2D graphics) i think it's quite common. Although i think it is still possible to get benefit from indices with some tricks (depending on actual use-cases).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it's better to use indices in many cases since you don't have to store or transfer duplicate vertices and you don't have to process duplicate vertices (vertex shader only needs to be run once per vertex). In the case of quads, you reduce 6 vertices to 4, plus a small amount of index data. Two thirds is quite a good improvement really, especially if your vertex data is more than just position.

In summary, `glDrawElements` results in

- Less data (mostly), which means more GPU memory for other things
- Faster updating if the data changes
- Faster transfer to the GPU
- Faster vertex processing (no duplicates)

Indexing can affect cache performance, if the reference vertices that aren't near each other in memory. Modellers commonly produce meshes which are optimized with this in mind.

For multiple elements, if you're referring to `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP` you *could* use [`glPrimitiveRestartIndex`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/xhtml/glPrimitiveRestartIndex.xml) to draw multiple strips of triangles with the one `glDrawElements` call. In your case it's easy enough to use `GL_TRIANGLES` and reference 4 vertices with 6 indices for each quad. Your vertex array then needs to store all the vertices for all your quads. If they're moving you still need to send that data to the GPU every frame. You could position all the moving quads at the front of the array and only update the active ones. You could also store static vertex data in a separate array.

The typical approach to drawing a 3D model is to provide a list of fixed vertices for the geometry and move the whole thing with the *model* matrix (as part of the model-view). The confusing part here is that the mesh data is so small that, as you say, the overhead of the draw calls may become quite prominent. I think you'll have to draw a *LOT* of quads before you get to the stage where it'll be a problem. However, if you do, instancing or some similar idea such as particle systems is where you should look.

Perhaps only go down the following track if the draw calls or data transfer becomes a problem as there's a lot involved. A good way of implementing particle systems entirely on the GPU is to store instance attributes such as position/colour in a texture. Each frame you use an FBO/render-to-texture to "ping-pong" this data between another texture and update the attributes in a fragment shader. To draw the particles, you can set up a static VBO which stores quads with the attribute-data texture coordinates for use in the vertex shader where the particle position can be read and applied. I'm sure there's a bunch of good tutorials/implementations to follow [out there](https://www.google.com/search?q=opengl+particle+system+ping+pong+texture) (please comment if you know of a good one).

Comment: To add to primitive restart (which is what I'd recommend too, nowadays), one could mention degenerate tris as an alternative. Though that's admittedly late-1990s stuff.

Comment: In my demo, I'll be drawing a lot of moving quads but only in 2D.
Would using glPrimitveRestartIndex or degenerate tris(no clue what that is) allow me to draw many quads that are unconnected? (Like a quad that's at the top of the screen and another at the bottom?

Comment: @Darkalfx TBH, I'd start by creating a single VBO that draws just one quad for all moving objects, and position it with the modelview matrix. For the level and static stuff, use `GL_TRIANGLES` and lump as much as you can into the same VBO. Primitive restart and degenerates are more for drawing many triangle strips, which in your case could save one an extra index per quad. Probably a case of premature optimization. Putting all moving objects into the same VBO might give a speedup but the particles method will be fastest (but much more complicated).

Comment: Ah, that seems to make sense.
Although, being new to opengl and everything, what's a VBO?

Comment: A VBO is a [Vertex Buffer Object](https://www.google.com/search?q=opengl+introduction+OR+tutorial+vertex+buffer+object). With VBOs, you can upload all of your vertex and index data to GPU memory. If you have mesh data that doesn't change, drawing is *much* faster. If not, it's similar in speed to drawing from arrays in system memory.